# Why 99-9 stronger than Q-QQ for Ivey vs Moneymaker?

Tags: rules

Watching this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMhjBupS4_E

and wondering why at the 8m35 mark, Ivey has 999 but is 83% favourite to win against QQQ. Isn't QQQ stronger than 999?

Best regards,

Bertrand

Comment: Oh, never mind. I realised my mistake not seeing QQ on Ivey's side also.

Comment: I suggest you just delete the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP simple misunderstood something and has no good answer but look again OP.

Answer (score 1):

The pair of queens on the board gives Ivey a full house 9s full of queens ahead of trips